# xfrac and anyfontsize cause missing superscripts in $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, xfrac, anyfontsize

Using `anyfontsize` and `xfrac` together seems to break superscripts within inline math.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

$\frac{1}{x^2}$ (good)

$\sfrac{1}{2}$  (good)

$\frac{1}{x^2}$ (very small exponent font)

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: render]

Is there a reason for this? Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes there is a conflict between the 2 packages.  If you use text  only for the `\sfrac`, i.e., remove the `$` it will work. I guess because the two packages interfere with the font selection. By the way if you want to use Vulgar fractions rather use unicode symbols, like  ½ Vulgar Fraction One Half.

Comment: The superscript displays correctly when I change the math font (e.g., to `notomath` or `libertinust1math`). Could it be a font-specific bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The start of `anyfontsize.sty` is

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{anyfontsize}[2007/11/22 anyfontsize.sty by pts]
```

In more than sixteen years, many things have changed. In particular, the package goes on with

```
%** Overrides definition in latex.ltx
%** See %%%% pts %%%% for the overridden part.
```

Don't use it.

Instead, if you only plan to use CM fonts, issue

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

before your `\documentclass` line.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

$\frac{1}{x^2}$ (good)

$\sfrac{1}{2}$  (good)

$\frac{1}{x^2}$ (very small exponent font)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use `lmodern`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex}

\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

$\frac{1}{x^2}$ (good)

$\sfrac{1}{2}$  (good)

$\frac{1}{x^2}$ (very small exponent font)

\end{document}
```

[image]