xfrac behaves weird with babel and anyfontsize
I use the xfrac package to make nice looking fractions, and I noticed some weird behavior of this package. Let's begin with this simple example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sfrac{x^2}{y^2}
\end{align*}
\[ \sfrac{x^2}{y^2} \]
\end{document}

which produces

This seems to work, but it gives me a warning: LaTeX Font: Size substitutions with differences (Font)  up to 3.25pt have occurred.. I don't understand where this warning comes from, but I was able to fix it (and other similar warnings I encountered in the past) with the anyfontsize package:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}  % Fixes weird warning

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sfrac{x^2}{y^2}
\end{align*}
\[ \sfrac{x^2}{y^2} \]
\end{document}

which produces:

Now I don't get any warnings, but the exponents are extremely tiny that I almost thought they weren't rendered at all. I don't understand what happened here. Another issue occurs since I normally use babel with Hebrew, which reverses the output in the align* environment for some reason:
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sfrac{x^2}{y^2}
\end{align*}
\[ \sfrac{x^2}{y^2} \]
\end{document}


These problems are unrelated since commenting out the anyfontsize package fixes the exponents and brings back the warnings, but the output is still reversed in the align* environment:

I can't figure out what is going on here and how I can fix this. I'd really appreciate any insights or fixes for these issues.

do not use anyfontsize. Use \RequirePackage{fix-cm} before \documentclass. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707478/2388

and better do not ask two unrelated questions in one question.
